# Using Facebook Graph API, how can I print a user's full name in a standalone ruby code?

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to learn Facebook Graph API but don't know how to start. For example, how can I get the object representing user with ID 1234567 and print the full name in standard output? I want to do it in a standalone ruby code, without having to host the code in some website.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible with That Data want an authentication for access it.

such as email, likes, bio and so on

But If you access 'public user's profile' 
You can connect "http://graph.facebook.com/username" to access it.